# C++11 Thread- doesn't compile when I pass in unordered_map argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a function which looks like

```
void MyClass::X(char* a, long b, std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I> > c){

}
```

and I want to call this function from a thread inside the constructor of MyClass:

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I> > c){
    std::thread t1(X, a, b, c);
}
```

Header for MyClass:

```
class MyClass{

public:
    MyClass(std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I> > c);
    ~MyClass();
    void X(char* a, long b, std::unordered_map<std::string,boost::shared_ptr<I> > c);
    char* a;
    long b;

private:

};
```

However I get nasty errors like below (when I comment out the thread line above, the code compiles fine):

```
error : no instance of overloaded function "std::_Pmf_wrap<_Pmf_t, _Rx, _Farg0, _V0_t, _V1_t, _V2_t, _V3_t, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil>::operator() [with _Pmf_t=void (MyClass::*)(char *, long, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>>, std::unordered_map<std::string,
1>            boost::shared_ptr<I>, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>>>>), _Rx=void, _Farg0=MyClass, _V0_t=char *, _V1_t=long, _V2_t=std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>>, _V3_t=std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>, std::hash<std::string>,
1>            std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>>>>]" matches the argument list
1>              argument types are: (char *, long, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>>, std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>>>>)
1>              object type is: std::_Pmf_wrap<void (MyClass::*)(char *, long, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>>, std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>>>>), void, MyClass, char *, long,
1>                        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>>, std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>>>>, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil>
1>    _VARIADIC_EXPAND_0X(_CLASS_BIND, , , , )
1>    ^
1>            detected during:
1>              instantiation of "std::_Do_call_ret<_Forced, _Ret, std::decay<_Fun>::type, std::tuple<std::decay<_Vx0_t>::type, std::decay<_Vx1_t>::type, std::decay<_Vx2_t>::type, std::decay<_Vx3_t>::type, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil>, std::tuple<std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil>>::type std::_Bind<_Forced, _Ret, _Fun, _Vx0_t, _Vx1_t, _Vx2_t, _Vx3_t, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil>::operator()() [with _Forced=1, _Ret=void,
1>                        _Fun=std::_Pmf_wrap<void (MyClass::*)(char *, long, std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>>, std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>>>>), void, MyClass, char *, long, std::unordered_map<std::string,
1>                        std::string, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>>, std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>>>>, std::_Nil, std::_Nil, std::_Nil>, _Vx0_t=char *&, _Vx1_t=long &, _Vx2_t=std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string, std::hash<std::string>,
1>                        std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, std::string>>> &, _Vx3_t=std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>, std::hash<std::string>, std::equal_to<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, boost::shared_ptr<I>>>> &]" at line 195 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\thr/xthread"
```

Comment: Slightly related: You're threading a member function with no `this`.

Comment: Try `std::thread t1(&MyClass::X, this, a, b, c);`

Comment: @WhozCraig on the function name or data members?

Comment: @AndyProwl put as answer and will accept. Thanks too whozcraig

Comment: @user997112: I do not have time for crafting a decent answer. Please accept my apologies.

Comment: @AndyProwl what you put in comment was the answer :)

Comment: Note that the code that creates `t1` in the `MyClass` constructor will immediately destroy it; since the code neither joins nor detaches the thread, it will throw an exception. That's probably not what's intended...

Comment: @PeteBecker it will **not** throw an exception but explicitly call `std::terminate` (or equivalent substitute) if a thread is not `join`/`dettach`ed.

Comment: @refp - you're right. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Make `X` `static` to make that line compile.

This may prevent `X` from compiling.  If `X` uses `this`, you can either pass a pointer explicitly, or you can use the fact that `std::thread` auto converts member function pointers into flat functions that take `this` as the first argument.

```
std::thread t(&MyClass::X, this, a, b, c);
```

Finally, note that `std::thread` is a low level primitive that can easily crash your program if you use it wrong (joining and detatching and synchronizing oh my).  Consider using `std::async` or building your own wrapper around it instead of using it directly.